Horror movie with an alien switching heads
It was released maybe 15 years ago or more. Genre was comedy-horror, probably low-budget movie. I remember the main character was an alien in human shape who had an ability to swap its head with other humans' heads (after it kills them) and that gets him disguised to walk among society. I can't remember much of the main story. If someone know the name of the movie, I will be grateful.

Sounds very much like The Borrower from 1991.

The alien serial killer, who is sent to Earth to live among humans, which includes having his body genetically transformed to look like a human's. The transformation is incomplete and, after a while, the alien's body begins to revert to its original form. His head explodes, prompting him to "borrow" another from anyone who happens to be nearby. He gets it by squeezing the head off with a crab-like claw and skewering it onto his own neck.

Here's the trailer:



